# Floating point exception 8 in C

Tags: c, runtime-error

The following is a code (in [c](/questions/tagged/c), using `gcc` compilation) to compare the number of square-free numbers between two ranges, `[lower1, upper1]` and `[lower2, upper2]`. However, when executing it to compare `[1,5]` and `[5,9]`, I receive a

> floating point exception: 8

error, although I am not able to see a case where division by zero occurs. Any help would be appreciated to resolve this problem.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <math.h>
   int main(void)
   {
      int lower1, upper1, lower2, upper2,j,k,i = 2,c,count = 0,xcount = 0,
         a,a1,f;
      scanf("%i %i %i %i",&lower1, &upper1, &lower2, &upper2);
      j = lower1;
      k = lower2;
     while (lower1 <= upper1)
     {
        f = i*i;
        a = lower1 % f != 0;
        c = a&&a1;
        a1 = lower1 % f != 0;
        if (i <= ceil(sqrt(lower1))){
           count+=c;
           lower1++;
           i = 2;
        }
        else
           i++;
     }
     count -= j==1?1:0;
     a = a1 = 1;
     i = 2;
     while (lower2 <= upper2)
     {
           f = i*i;
           a = lower2 % f != 0;
           c = a&&a1;
           a1 = lower2 % f != 0;
           if (i <= ceil(sqrt(lower2))){
              xcount+=(c - lower2==1?1:0);
              lower2++;
              i = 2;
           }
           else
              i++;
     }
     count -= j==1?1:0;
     if (xcount>count)
        printf("Range [%i,%i] has more"
        "square-free numbers: %i\n",k,upper2,xcount);
     else if (xcount < count)
        printf("Range [%i,%i] has more"
           "square-free numbers:%i\n",j,upper1,count);
     else
        printf("Both have same number of square-free numbers:%i\n",count);
     return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Running it via a debugger should help you locate the point at which the exception occurs.  That may not be the actual locus of the problem, but it should help you figure out what is going on.  Indeed, a debugger would be more broadly helpful in such an effort.

Comment: I have used gcc -Wall filename.c, but it did not show any error.

Comment: Please don't post code with line numbers.

Comment: `c = a&&a1;` line 14 is UB as a1 has no value in the first call

Comment: If you want to do number theory problems, or integer math more generally, then it's a good idea to avoid floating-point altogether.  For example, instead of `i <= ceil(sqrt(lower2))`, use `i*i <= lower2`  (if indeed that's what you mean).  You do need to watch out for overflow, but it saves you from a number of FP-related problems, such as loss of precision.

Comment: oh and better variable names would be very good here....

Comment: _I have used gcc -Wall filename.c, but it did not show any error:_ your program may very well compile without errors/warnings but it still may be full of bugs.

Comment: Make sure that the divisor ((`f` here: `a = lower2 % f != 0;` and similar lines) is not 0.

Comment: Also, learn about functions.  It's both wasteful and error-prone to repeat substantially the same block of code for counting square-free numbers; this should go in a function.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have modified the code accordingly and it now works well. Although not strictly related to the main question, would there be a more efficient algorithm for this code (apart from using functions), i.e. using simpler structures and more elegant algorithms?

Comment: @user42520, yes, you can improve on the algorithm.  You perform a lot more computations than you need to do if your intervals' upper bounds are large.  You can use the fact that a number is divisible by a square if and only if it is divisible by the square of a prime, to reduce the number of computations -- sieve out the primes not exceeding the square root of the larger interval bound, then and eliminate multiples of *their* squares.  With a bit of care, you can even integrate the counting and sieving.